# Was für ein Wort ist "halt"?

Tags: etymology, vocabulary

Das Wort "halt" im Sinne von

> Das ist halt so.

ist in keine mir bekannte Sprache direkt übersetzbar.

Gibt es für diese Art Wort einen linguistischen Fachbegriff?

Wie wird die Funktion bezeichnet, die es erfüllt?

Kennt jemand nähere Informationen zu seiner Geschichte und Verbreitung? Wörterbücher und Lexika haben nichts zu bieten.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Im Deutschen kann man die **[Abtönungspartikel](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abt%C3%B6nungspartikel?title=Abt%C3%B6nungspartikel&redirect=no)** *halt* häufig mit *einfach* oder *eben* austauschen:

> Das ist einfach/eben so.

Im Sinne von *"Es ist so – ob man es will oder nicht."*

Im Englischen müsste man es je nach Kontext etwas umschreiben; manchmal passt auch das Wort *"just"* wie in dieser Übersetzung deines Beispiels:

> That's just the way it is.

Auf Italienisch gibt es das Wort *insomma* (eigentlich "alles in allem"), das voran- oder nachgestellt wird und umgangssprachlich häufig als Füllwort verwendet wird.

> È così insomma. ("So ist es halt.")

Was die [Herkunft](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/halt_nun_eben_nun_einmal) betrifft:

> Das alt- und mittelhochdeutsche *halt* bedeutete *mehr, vielmehr*; Komparativ zu althochdeutsch *halto* = sehr, ursprünglich vielleicht = geneigt und verwandt mit unter [Halde](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Halde) genanntem germanischem Adjektiv

In diesem [Artikel über die Historie der Partikelforschung](http://www.studiger.tu-dortmund.de/index.php?title=Historie_der_Partikelforschung#Beispiel_2%3a_Halt) findet sich zudem folgende ausführliche Erläuterung:

> Die Partikel *halt* wird als Abtönungspartikel (auch Modalpartikel genannt) genutzt. Halt wird ähnlich wie eben verwendet, jedoch lässt sich eben immer durch halt ersetzen, aber nicht umgekehrt. Zudem lassen sich regionale Präferenzen in der Verwendung feststellen. Halt ist eher im süddeutschen Raum anzutreffen und eben im norddeutschen, wobei halt auch im Norden zunehmend Verwendung findet.
>
> Bedeutungsentwicklung: Halt geht laut Hentschel (1986: 76 inkl. Übersetzung) auf eine Komparativform von „haldis“ → „mehr“ zurück und hatte im Ahd. temporale und modale Bedeutung, die durch „rasch, schnell, sofort, eher“ oder „vielmehr, lieber“ ersetzt werden kann. Die Meinungen dazu sind strittig. Teilweise wird der Standpunkt vertreten, dass halt sich nicht auf die genannte Komparativform zurückführen lassen könne (vgl. Diewald 1997: 93). Im Ahd. kommt Hentschel (1986: 77-79) zu dem Schluss, dass halt grammatikalisch dem Komparativ zuzuordnen ist und temporalen oder modalen Sinn haben kann, aber noch keine Partikelbedeutung hat.
>
> Im Mhd. hat halt noch die Bedeutung von „vielmehr, lieber, eher“ und wird neben diesen Begriffen als Modalpartikel verwendet. Für das Mhd. typisch wird halt in konzessiven Nebensätzen gebraucht, die beispielsweise durch „ob“ eingeleitet werden, und stellt einen Bezug zum pragmatischen Prätext her.
>
> In der weiteren sprachlichen Entwicklung ist halt nicht mehr im Sinne von "vielmehr, lieber, eher" gleichzusetzen, sondern teilweise durch die Verwendung von "auch" wiederzugeben. So stellt halt eine innertextliche Verbindung zwischen zwei Sachverhalten her.
>
> Im heutigen Gebrauch wird halt im übergeordneten Satz verwendet und stellt damit keine textlichen Verbindungen mehr her, sondern bezieht sich ausschließlich auf den „pragmatischen Prätext“. Der Schritt zur Abtönungspartikel ist somit vollzogen.

Answer (score 5):

Das [etymologische Wörterbuch des Deutschen (Pfeifer)](http://www.dwds.de/?kompakt=1&qu=halt) schreibt:

> halt Adv. ‘eben, wohl, schon, nun einmal’, ahd. (um 800), mhd. halt ‘mehr, vielmehr’, bes. bekräftigend ‘eben, freilich’, auch (mit Komparativendung) mhd. halter, asächs. hald, anord. heldr ‘vielmehr, eher’, schwed. heller, got. haldis ‘mehr’. halt ist endungsloser Adverbialkomparativ (ähnlich baß, s. d.) zum Positiv ahd. halto Adv. ‘bald, schnell, rasch’ (um 900). Die Herkunft ist nicht geklärt. Vielleicht zu einem Adjektiv ahd. hald ‘schräg, geneigt’ (s. Halde)? Die Ausgangsbedeutung ‘mehr’ begegnet mhd. nur noch vereinzelt; halt wird bekräftigend und begründend ( ‘eben, ja, freilich’) und im Nhd. vielfach einschränkend im Sinne eines Resignierens, Sichfügens (da kann man halt nichts machen) verwendet. Über das südd. Verbreitungsgebiet hinaus begegnet halt in jüngerer Zeit auch bei md. und nordd. Autoren.