# Was für ein Wort ist "Ei"/"Ai"?

Tags: single-word-request, dialect

[Diese Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/was-fur-ein-wort-ist-halt) ließ mich darüber nachdenken, woher eigentlich "Ei"/"Ai" kommt.
Da es sich lediglich um gesprochene Sprache handelt bin ich mir bei der Schreibweise unsicher.
Verwendet wird es in meiner Region (Mittelhessen) jedenfalls häufig am Satzanfang, beispielsweise bei Erklärungen.

> Ei, dann musst du nur Knopf A drücken und dann landest du im Menü!

oder auch in der Variation "Eija"

> Eija, was soll ich dazu noch großartig sagen?

In letzterem Beispiel erfüllt es primär die Funktion eines Füllworts, es dehnt lediglich die Aussage, verschafft ihr aber keinen größeren Wert.

Gibt es für solche Worte noch weitere Beispiele in anderen Dialekten?
Und, wie nennt man diese Art Wörter?
Kann man sie überhaupt als eigenständige Wörter bezeichnen?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Im Saarländischen ist „ei“ **keine Interjektion**, sondern ein [**Diskursmarker**](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diskurspartikel) (vergleichbar mit dem englischen „well“ oder dem einleitenden „also“ im Hochdeutschen).

- Interjektionen „drücken [...] eine bestimmte Empfindung, Bewertungs- oder Willenshaltung des Sprechers aus oder übermitteln eine an den Empfänger gerichtete Aufforderung oder ein Signal der Kontaktaufnahme oder -vermeidung“ ([Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interjektion)).
- Diskurspartikel hingegen steuern lediglich das Gespräch. Wenn ich  „ei“ benutze, ist das kein Ausdruck einer Emotion; es bedeutet lediglich „nachfolgend sage ich etwas“.

Deswegen können Interjektionen auch für sich alleine stehen – „wow“, „igitt“, „autsch“, „nanu“, „huch“, „upps“ oder „auweia“ drücken ganz bestimmte Dinge aus, auch wenn nichts mehr folgt; „ei“ und „also“ tun das nicht.

Comment: Ah, stimmt, das kommt auch der Verwendung in meiner Region sehr Nahe. Ich hätte vielleicht lieber den Haken hier gesetzt :/

Comment: @Jemus: Du kannst das Häkchen immer noch umsetzen, wenn Du willst. (Ich denke, splattne wird nicht böse sein, wenn er die 15 Punkte Reputation verliert.)

Comment: Als überraschte Zustimmung kann man in direkter Rede auch, meine ich, "Ei!" rufen, und tadelnd, wenn die Katze unerlaubt am Fenster kratzt: "Also ...!"

Comment: "nanu" kann eigentlich nur alleine stehen, wenn die Überraschung, die mit der Interjektion bezeichnet wird, stärker war als der Sprecher. Also, in diesem Sinne sei an das passende Witze-Schema erinnert, "was waren die letzten Worte des Elektrikers?". Insgesamt ist es nicht sinnvoll, diese Diskursmarker von Interjektionen zu trennen. "Ei, da weiß ich was" ist doch sehr gut mit "Nanu, das weiß ich gar nicht" vergleichbar ... bei dem ein oder anderen eventuell auch andersherum "nanu, da weiß ich gar was".

Answer (score 12):

Wörter wie *"ei"* nennt man **Interjektionen** (aus dem lateinischen Wort für *Einwürfe*) oder **Ausrufewörter** (auch Empfindungswörter). Interjektionen haben keine syntaktische Funktion. Sie gehören zu den Partikeln und sind daher nicht flektierbar.

Das Wort *"ei"* drückt eine wohlgefällige Überraschung aus. Obwohl es im Allgemeinen als veraltet gilt, wird es regional noch häufig verwendet (Baden-Württemberg, Hessen …).

Das Wort selbst ist – wie andere **diphthongische Interjektionen** – sehr alt und ist bereits im Indogermanischen enthalten.

Andere Beispiele: *ach, aua, aha, igitt, hey, oje* usw. Manche Interjektionen sind vieldeutig und können je nach dem Inhalt der Aussage verschiedene Empfindungen ausdrücken (Freude, Schmerz, Furcht, Spott, Überraschung, …)

Viele Dialekte haben eigene Interjektionen. Im Bayerischen gibt es z. B. den typischen Ausruf *"oha"*.

Comment: "Ei" (oder "ei gudd") hört man auch im Saarland sehr oft.

Comment: Ei, ich wünschte ich könnte für diese Antwort 2x voten. Meinen Respekt!

Comment: @Markus Hey, danke!