# Benutzung der Abtönungspartikel »halt«

Tags: meaning, single-word-request

Ich verstehe noch nicht, wie *halt* als Abtönungspartikel zu verwenden ist. Aus [dieser Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/was-fur-ein-wort-ist-halt) lässt sich herausfinden, dass *halt* durch *eben* und *einfach* ersetzbar ist. Da wird auch Folgendes erwähnt:

> Im heutigen Gebrauch wird halt im übergeordneten Satz verwendet und stellt damit keine textlichen Verbindungen mehr her, sondern bezieht sich ausschließlich auf den **„pragmatischen Prätext“**. Der Schritt zur Abtönungspartikel ist somit vollzogen.

Den Begriff im Fettdruck verstehe ich auch nicht. Z. B. sind diese Sätze und deren Interpretation richtig?

- Ich verstehe halt deine Erklärungen nicht! (halt=einfach)
- Ich will halt diesen Pullover (halt=eben, genau,sehr)

Da ich sehr oft dieses Teilchen höre, würde ich auch gerne über ein breiteres Bedeutungsspektrum verfügen. Könnte jemand weitere Beispiele hinzufügen?

Comment: Der _pragmatische Prätext_ ist, grob gesagt, die Situation, in der etwas geäußert wird (vgl. [Pragmatik](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragmatik_%28Linguistik%29) bei Wikipedia). Es ist ein Fachausdruck, den auch Deutsche nicht verstehen werden, wenn sie keine Linguisten sind.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Dein erstes Beispiel wäre in Ordnung, wenn *halt* vor *nicht* steht. Die Verwendung ist dann äquivalent zu dem "Das ist halt so"-Beispiel. Das verleiht in dem Beispiel halt noch einen Nachdruck, mag aber auch unterstreichen, dass es sich hier um eine Tatsache handelt.

Wie aus Wiktionary zu entnehmen, hat *[halt](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/halt)* im Wesentlichen zwei Funktionen. Zum einen kann man damit einen Fakt unterstreichen (= *Das ist halt so*), zum anderen das Gesagte nochmal betonen, hervorheben; also einen Nachdruck verleihen.

Dein zweites Beispiel ist zwar korrekt, ist mir im ersten Moment dennoch spanisch vorgekommen. *Halt* ist in dem Beispiel nicht synonym zu *genau*. Wenn du sagst, "Ich will genau diesen Pullover", dann bezieht sich *genau* auf den Pullover. Diesen halt, und keinen anderen. Die Verwendung von *halt* hier hat aber die Funktion, dass es halt so ist, wie es ist.

> Ich will genau diesen Pullover und nicht den anderen.
>   Ich will halt[=eben] diesen Pullover. Ist so. Kannste nix machen.

*Sehr* kannst du in dem Beispiel nur verwenden, wenn du es nach hinten stellst:

> Ich will diesen Pullover sehr. Ich will ihn unbedingt. Ich muss ihn einfach haben.

Hier hat *sehr* halt die Funktion einer Steigerung. Du willst ihn nicht nur, du willst ihn auf jeden Fall.

Wie dir vielleicht aufgefallen ist, habe ich sehr oft in dieser Antwort *halt* verwendet. Es besagt quasi immer: *Das ist halt so. So wird es im Sprachgebrauch halt angewandt.* Das ist in Wiktionary abgedeckt durch:

> Gewohnheit und Beständigkeit betreffend

Die zweite Definition (*Ausdruck, der einer Aufforderung oder einem Ratschlag Nachdruck verleiht*) wird in der Umgangssprache auch häufig verwendet, wenn du genervt bist.

> A sagt zum x-ten Mal: "Ich hab Kopfschmerzen."
>   B: "Dann geh halt zum Arzt."

Du sagst nicht nur, dass A zum Arzt gehen soll, sondern, dass A es endlich machen und dir nicht mehr auf die Nerven gehen soll.

Comment: OK, danke. Es käme mir komisch vor, »halt halt das Auto!« oder »Halt halt die Klappe« zu hören.

Comment: @c.p. *"halt halt die Klappe"*, ist ***rein theoretisch*** dieselbe Konstruktion wie "*geh halt zum Arzt"*

Comment: Das "Halt halt!" hallt halt nach.

Comment: *Ich verstehe halt deine Erklärung nicht* kommt mir auch spanisch vor, aber inakzeptabel würde ich es nicht finden. Bin der Meinung das ist so durchaus zu hören. Formell ist es halt sowieso nicht.

Answer (score 8):

Die Partikel *halt*, wie du sie hier beschreibst, ist rein umgangssprachlich und wird nie in geschriebenem Text auftauchen.
Sie drückt aus, dass etwas selbstverständlich oder banal ist und keiner weiteren Ausführung bedarf – aus Sicht des Redners.

*Halt* wird also fast immer verwendet, wenn man seine Meinung nicht weiter erklären kann oder will. Dadurch wirkt die Aussage meist schroff und unhöflich.

> Ich mag halt keine Leber.
>
> „Mama, warum ist der Himmel blau?“ – „Das ist halt so.“

Nur wenn *halt* in Bezug auf eine Sache verwendet wird, in der sich alle Anwesenden einig sind, ist es nicht unhöflich.

> Die Klausur war halt schon verdammt schwer.

Comment: Ah! Mögliche *(Un)höflichkeitsbedeutungen* sind immer wichtig zu diskutieren!

Answer (score 2):

"Das ist halt so".

Hier deutet "halt" einfach an, dass man keine Erklärung für 
etwas hat. Dieses "halt", Modalitätspartikel, hat nichts mit 
dem Verb halten zu tun. Es besagt: Es ist so, wie es ist; ich kann/man
kann nicht erklären, warum es so ist.