# Can someone explain how “halt” is used idiomatically?

Tags: meaning

> Ich mag halt alles geordnet.

Was bedeutet "halt"?

Comment: Related: [Benutzung der Abtönungspartikel »halt«](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/8435/9551)

Comment: "Ich mag halt alles geordnet" == "I like things orderly, is all."

Answer (score 7):

"halt" in this case doesn't mean "stop".
You could translate this to "I just like when everything's in order."
The english "just" is the only translation that makes sense for me in thise case.

Sidenote: another word like this is the german "eben". Just like "halt" it has another meaning (flat, even or level) but is synonymous to "halt". e.g. *Ich mag eben Alles geordnet.*

Comment: those words are used for further confirmation, to put emphasis on what you say or mean, or to make clear that there's no use to further discuss what you just said